# Unity Stitching meshes together

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I've been thinking on this for a few days and have tried a few different things and have googled quite a bit. Iv specifically looked at this thread alot

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/

But im confused, and not sure if this 100% what i wanted.

Im just trying to add a new mesh to an already existing gameobject with its own mesh. That runs off the same bone structure or animator, the object being added has the required bones of the position its being pasted at.

https://gyazo.com/19778b3c73ef9a749c8cc338f7e49d79

Thats the object im trying to add onto my player. I tried taking the mesh directly off of it and then linking it to the same bone structure as the player being animated

When the object is created and imported with fuse/mixamo it adds the object as separate mesh objects on a parent player

https://gyazo.com/55ce7442dc186756da4ff149ac3543e5

So if i was to disable the armor mesh id be left with this

https://gyazo.com/09ffd7c7721f46e6980f895a1a873749

But i tried importing my character without the armor on it. Then i opened the character with the player and armor in blender and deleted the player and left the bone structure and the armor and then saved that as a separate fbx and imported that into unity and am pasting the new armor fbx on the original player in an attempt for it too animate the same was it originally was from the mixmo object. But it doesnt, cant even get it to import in Tpose. And when i configure it myself it wont save the configuration and just keeps going back to where it was.

I suppose i should.... only have the bones required on the armor. Then do some type of game logic to figure out what bones are the same name on the armor object as is being added to the player and replacing the player bones with the bone of the armor? But i feel like if i wanted to do it this way, then i need the player split into pieces so that it knows what parts to replace of the player. Or is there a way i can keep the player together and just make the armor follow the bones of the player, i guess would be the easiest thing to do

Im pretty sure the link i posted is pretty much waht i want. I guess i just dont understand it fully and wanted someone to help me better understand it

Comment: Iv actually managed to get it working and will write out a detailed tutorial explaining my methods of getting it working. I just need a bit to work it out better

Comment: https://gyazo.com/19c49bd6d2ee32874bacbb0fc58f22c3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, this post is not going to be explaining how the code works but how to get the code TOOOOO work. Masterprompt explains the code well enough [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/). If you want to understand how the code works follow that link.

Anyways, onto what to do to go about merging 2 objects together to make one object that runs off the animation of the base object.

Example uses could be

- Creating a person limb from limb.
- Add armor too a base player

The meat and bones of how i get this too work without having a graphic artist to create my assets for me is using fuse and mixamo. I highly suggest these programs. You can still easily get this too work without those programs, but i will be explaining how to do it as if you are using it.

Ok so, download Adobe fuse and create your base player. (preferably naked)
Now save that player as whatever you would like (I used Main_Player_Naked)
Upload this player to mixamo for auto rigging, after downloading the model from mixamo import him into unity. (At this point im assuming you know how to set the model up as a humanoid in unity)

Now that your player is created and imported into unity go ahead and animate him or do whatever you want with him. Whatever you do to him will work fine with the new armor/hair/beard whatever you are adding to your player.

Ok, now time to create the armor we are going to add. Go ahead and reopen your naked player in fuse and recreate him with the new asset you want him to have (Dont change any body shape sizes, just add the new object). (Don't worry we're not switching the whole model out, this is just so we don't have to rig the new asset by ourselves) Now that you have the new asset looking nice, go ahead and follow the first steps of creating the naked played. So save your newly created character and import to mixamo for auto-rigging. Now download and import the new player into unity. Delete all the objects off the player except the new asset (Which is on a separate mesh that the naked player that's under the object)

Now we are going to use the code from Masterprompts post

I've rewritten it, so here's my new code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CreatePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject objPlayer;
    public GameObject objLimb;
    public GameObject objAdded;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
            AddLimb(objLimb, objPlayer);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
            Destroy(objAdded);
    }

    // 

    void AddLimb(GameObject BonedObj, GameObject RootObj)
    {
        var BonedObjects = BonedObj.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer SkinnedRenderer in BonedObjects)
        {
            ProcessBonedObject(SkinnedRenderer, RootObj);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessBonedObject(SkinnedMeshRenderer ThisRenderer, GameObject RootObj)
    {
        /*      Create the SubObject        */
        var NewObj = new GameObject(ThisRenderer.gameObject.name);
        NewObj.transform.parent = RootObj.transform;
        /*      Add the renderer        */
        NewObj.AddComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        var NewRenderer = NewObj.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        /*      Assemble Bone Structure     */
        var MyBones = new Transform[ThisRenderer.bones.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < ThisRenderer.bones.Length; i++)
            MyBones[i] = FindChildByName(ThisRenderer.bones[i].name, RootObj.transform);
        /*      Assemble Renderer       */
        NewRenderer.bones = MyBones;
        NewRenderer.sharedMesh = ThisRenderer.sharedMesh;
        NewRenderer.materials = ThisRenderer.materials;
        objAdded = NewObj;
    }


    private Transform FindChildByName(string ThisName,Transform ThisGObj)
    {
        Transform ReturnObj;
        if( ThisGObj.name==ThisName )
            return ThisGObj.transform;
        foreach (Transform child in ThisGObj)
        {
            ReturnObj = FindChildByName( ThisName, child );
            if( ReturnObj )
                return ReturnObj;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This was very quickly thrown together. I suggest making it nicer.

But just add the naked player too objPlayer and the asset to add to objLimb.

Run your game and pushing 'H' creates the asset and 'J' deletes it.

Comment: One thing i would like to know, is how to get import only the new asset instead of having to import the whole character and delete the unneeded ones

Comment: ALso figured that out, doesn't seem to work in blender. But in MODO, i opened the player file with the armor on, deleted everything but the armature and the armor and exported it as fbx.